# mkfs doesn't work using fabric

Tags: boto, fabric

I am writing a python script that creating an amazon volume and attach it to an instance using boto.
To do so, I need to create a file system using mkfs command.
So, I wrote this code:

```
with settings(host_string=instance.public_dns_name, user = "my_user", key_filename="my_pem", warn_only=True):
    run('mkfs.ext4 /dev/xvdh')
    run('mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdh /work')
```

It returns:

```
Could not stat /dev/xvdh --- No such file or directory
The device apparently does not exist; did you specify it correctly?
```

I tries multiple options:

- using sudo rather than run
- using pty=False and/or shell=False in the run command

I SSHed to the VM and executed these commands, and it works fine! but didn't working using fabric.

Answer (score 1):

While this might not be a direct fix, its a definite alternative if all you need is a bigger drive on the instance anyways. You can do something like this with Boto to create the drive and the instance (which you probably have similar already, I took this out of my code and cleaned up so there might be a few extra settings in there)

Step1: Create the instance with a block device

```
def run_instances():
    dev_sda1 = BlockDeviceType()
    bdm = BlockDeviceMapping()
    bdm['/dev/sda1'] = dev_sda1
    reservation = ec2_conn.run_instances(
        default_ami[ec2_conn.region.name],
        min_count=count,
        max_count=count,
        **user_data=generate_userdata_base64(),**
        key_name='yourkey',
        security_groups=ec2_security_groups,
        instance_type=instance_type,
        **block_device_map=bdm,**
        placement=placement
    )
```

The docs have of course way more info:
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.blockdevicemapping

Step2: prep the device

Use **resize2fs** *instead of creating the volume*, the previous block mapping device will swap the normal instance device for an EBS volume or blockstore and load the default AMI data onto it, then all you need is to extend the partition instead of creating a new one.

I like to create a base64 user data script, just cause it makes life easier to perform some base initialization tasks when you're first booting your instance (while you're using fab why not go all at it).

```
def generate_userdata_base64():
    script = '#!/bin/bash\n\n'
    script += 'resize2fs /dev/sda1\n'
    script += 'yum update -y\n'
    return base64.b64encode(script)
```

and you can add anything else to that like base daemons to install or start, users to add, etc. I hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks @RageLink. However, this solution is not what I need. I want the attached volume to be independent than the one with the AMI data.

Comment: Mainly something like this
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Comment: If you are using anything other than amazon linux you might have to stat the block storage device or rescan for devices before you mount them... try 
`sudo partprobe` 

before you do... if that doesnt work you can always try fdisk before even creating the partition, something like 

`$ sudo sfdisk /dev/sdb < custom.layout` 

and you can define a file or some string that will create the layout based on examples or something like this even:
[http://serverfault.com/questions/320590/non-interactively-create-one-partition-with-all-available-disk-size]